# JavaScript check if string is empty during onClick function

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone advise me what is wrong with the empty String check in the JavaScript below.

It works fine if I remove the line of code which checks for empty String, but I would like to display "Nothing selected" if the selection is empty.

```
<html>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  function update()
  {
    var selection = "";
    var empty = "";
    if (document.form1.TeaName.checked)    selection += "Tea<br>";
    if (document.form1.CoffeeName.checked) selection += "Coffee<br>";
    if (document.form1.EggsName.checked)   selection += "Eggs<br>";
    if (document.form1.BaconName.checked)  selection += "Bacon<br>";
    if (selection.equals(empty)) selection = "Nothing selected.";
    document.getElementById("currentSelection").innerHTML = selection;
  }
  -->
  </script>
  <body>
    <form name="form1">
      <div id="container" style="width:100%">
        <div id="left" style="float:left; width: 30%;">
          <h3>List 1</h3>
          <input type="checkbox" onClick="update()" name="TeaName"    value="Tea">Tea<br>
          <input type="checkbox" onClick="update()" name="CoffeeName" value="Coffee">Coffee<br>
        </div>
        <div id="middle" style="float:left; width: 30%;">
          <h3>List 2</h3>
          <input type="checkbox" onClick="update()" name="EggsName"  value="Eggs">Eggs<br>
          <input type="checkbox" onClick="update()" name="BaconName" value="Bacon">Bacon<br>
        </div>
        <div id="right" style="float:left; width: 30%;">
          <h3>Currently selected</h3>
          <p id="currentSelection">Please make a selection.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time,

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such method `equals`. Don't complicate things:

```
if (selection.length === 0) selection = "Nothing selected.";
```

Answer (score 2):

replace this row:

```
 if (selection.equals(empty)) selection = "Nothing selected.";
```

with this:

```
 if (selection == "" ) selection = "Nothing selected.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!selection) selection="Nothing selected.";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no equals function  in javascript, you either have to check with the length or a simple === operator

```
if (selection.length<= 0) selection = "Nothing selected.";

               (OR)

if(selection === "") selection  = "Nothing selected";

              (OR)

selection=(selection.length > 0) ? selection : "Nothing selected";
```

The function equals you have used should be related to some javascript library or framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have default text and skip the last check.

```
var selection = "Nothing selected."; //default text
// your rest of the code.
```

OR

Last check can be done as

```
selection = selection || "Nothing selected.";
```